# Google Map, Validation

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, styles

I have may be simple question, but I'm stuck up here

I have Google map iframe, but i need to pass validation and have no idea how to change the Google map code to make it work

Example:

```
  <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=bh15+5rf&amp;aq=&amp;sll=50.779458,-1.93428&amp;sspn=0.131771,0.316544&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=BH15,+United+Kingdom&amp;t=m&amp;z=13&amp;ll=50.730003,-1.985543&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />
```

Some relevant answer here:
[Displaying Google map in IE using <div> <object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190229/displaying-google-map-in-ie-using-div-object)

But no one answer.

Can any one help, to pass validation with Google maps

Comment: may be this help for you  https://gist.github.com/gabesumner/1801479 (or)  http://gabesumner.com/address-validation-using-the-google-maps-api

Answer (score 1):

It validates if you remove the elements - frameborder="0" scrolling="no".
Framborder can be replaced by adding border:0 in your css stylesheet,  but removing scrolling can cause issues for older versions of IE.  For more info see:
http://www.maxdesign.com.au/2011/03/10/iframe-scrollbars-and-html5/